# How to fetch From Previous Month to Current Month today's Only

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a formula to do some calculation for pay period, I want to display only days between previous month 21th to current month's today.

Eg.**2021-May-21 to 2021-June-18** 
*(2021-May-21 the starting date of previous month will always be **21st** to end date should be today's day (will be adding day by day) up to **20th** of current month)*

I came up with something like this

```
=ArrayFormula(ADD(DATE(YEAR(today()),MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)),21),row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(today()),MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),today())))))
```

But It didn't come up to my expectation, Can you help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: type the date 21-06-2021 in A1
Step-2: copy the formula in cell A2

Forumula:
=IF(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))<EDATE(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),1),IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))>EDATE(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),1),DAYS(EDATE(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),1),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))),DAYS(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())+1),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))))

How it works?:
criteria-1: checks if the date "21-06-2021" is lessthan with the addition of 1 month in the given date (i.e. 21-06-2021 plus 1 month = 21-07-2021) then current days is return (i.e. 6);
criteria-2:checks if current date is greaterthan 21-07-2021 then final days is return (i.e. 31)